# How do I make sense of 具备……条件?

Tags: meaning, word

It seems 具备 and 条件 form a collocation, such as:

> ……，我**具备**今年参加司法考试的所有的**条件**，……
> ..., I **possess** all of this year's judicial test's **requirements**, ...
> <sub>Source: [random Chinese government website](http://www.putian.gov.cn/znhdwdk/ssfj/sfks/201309/t20130930_245480.htm).</sub>

However, this doesn't make sense in English: the "requirements" don't belong to "me", they belong to someone else: I can't possess someone else's requirements (however, I could *satisfy* them, or I could have the *qualifications*).  So I have no intuition on how this works.

My dictionary gives the definitions:

> 具备：(动) **具有**；齐备
> 条件：(名) 1: 形象事物存在和发展变化的诸因素。 2: 规定应遵守的**要求**、标准。 3: 状况。

It seems like 我具备……条件 doesn't make sense in Chinese for the same reason: the 条件 belong to someone else, therefore I cannot 具备 them.  Thus, if it was me writing, I would use 我**具备**……所需要的**资格** or 我**满足**……所有的**条件**.

**Question**: How do I make sense of 具备……条件?

Comment: How about, in this context, translate 条件 as "qualifying requirements"? And 具备 as "meet" or as you say "satisfy" So, the English version goes like "I meet / satisfy all of this year's judicial test's qualifying requirements" And, yes, a singular translation of 具备 as "possess" is restrictive in English which ordinarily confines "possess" to something that amounts to "ownership", or "personal belongings", rather than "possessing" a certain personal "attribute" which is what 具备 is meant in this context.

Answer (score 4):

条件: requirement; condition; required qualification

条件 here should be interpreted as '**required qualification** ' not 'requirement'

> 我**具备**今年参加司法考试的所有的**条件**

> I **possess** all of this year's judicial test's **required qualifications**

More Example:

Hire the qualified = Hire the qualified (applicant)

Help the poor = Help the poor (people)

Have all the required = Have all the required (elements)

Disambiguation:

- **有条件的**人择偶会比较容易 - The ones who **have required qualities** have an easier time finding a mate
- 让你入会是**有条件的** - Your admission is **conditional**
- 入会的**条件**是月入超过十万美元 = The **requirement** for joining the club is a monthly income over $100,000/ The **required qualification** for joining the club is a monthly income over $100,000

Answer (score 2):

**"... the 条件 belong to someone else, therefore I cannot 具备"** - Wrong.

In concerns of personal qualifications, 条件 can be interpreted as 資格, for example,

- 我有(具备)**条件**去參加.... = 我有(具备)**資格**去參加...
- 我**条件**不夠. = 我**資格**不夠. "不夠" = "不具备".

The uses of these two words differ slightly. "資格" is more pertaining to the personal education, experience, and moral qualifications; 条件 covers the former two qualifications, physical conditions, and social-economic status of a person. Both can be possessed by anybody, including self.

Comment: an upvote for the interpretation 条件 as 资格

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any problem with "requirements". Certain preconditions are necessary before you may sit the exam.

我具备今年参加司法考试的所有的条件.
I have all the requirements for participating in this year's Judicial Official Exam.